# Bootstrap CSS: Get tags-styling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tags

Is there a possibility to get [this](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) styling with bootstrap without having to use the jQuery stuff?

Want the same styling but logic with Vue.js 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at 
https://tucci.me/vue-input-tag/

just the same.. styling is css only

Comment: yeah thats an option, but I just made my own styling: https://jsfiddle.net/tru4k9o7/